# Show text in Label when typing any text inside TextField

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have simple app , built using JavaFX.

I have one `Button`, one `TextField` and one `Label` beside the `TextField`.

My Question is: How can I show the text on the `Label` while typing text inside the `TextField` before click the `Button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply bind the `textProperty` of the `Label` to the `textProperty` of the `TextField`.

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
Label label = new Label();

label.textProperty().bind(tf.textProperty());
```

Comment: Thanks , that's helpful , But i'm using fxml file for layout , i  found  solution passing fx-id TextField to Text label   <Label ... text=${TextField-id.text} />

Answer (score 1):

```
    <TextField fx-id="textField" />  <Label text="${textField.text}"/>
```

Thanks , for help ,  for me this solution helpful